# Plotting several graph of txt files

Tags: plotting

I have several txt files (t1.txt,t2.txt,...). Each file have two column with the datas x and y. I want plotting the datas of each file in diferents grahs and show all. I know plotting one file but I don't know do it with several txt files both.

Comment: You need to assign the files to different variables, or different parts of the same variable, then feed them all to the plotting function together.  Like `lists = Table[ Import["t"<>IntegerString[n]<>".txt","Table"], {n,1,5}]; ListLinePlot[lists]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment JasonB. I try this how you tell me: SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\MGR\\Desktop\\prueba"];
files = FileNames["*.txt"];
n = Length[files]
lists = Table[
  Import["t" <> IntegerString[i] <> ".txt", "Table"], {i, 1, 
   n}]; ListLinePlot[lists] but only plotting one graph of the first file.

Comment: That should have worked.  What does `lists` look like after you run that?  What is the result from `Dimensions[lists]`?  Also, if you have the list of files like that you can shorten the code to `lists = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ files;` but that should be the same as what you have there.

Comment: For example, I have three files in the directory.     Dimensions[lists] is 3. I tried with    lists = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ files    but the results is the same. Only appear one graph corresponding to the firts file. It should show three graphs.

Comment: Without the files I can't say more.  But the next step is to look at `lists[[1]]`, `lists[[2]]`, and `lists[[3]]` and see if their contents are the same as the files you imported.

Comment: These are the file: https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pl/prueba/_5609ff57121a4cf9969492807f3a09ef.  The contents are diferents. I tried with other code:  m=Table[data[[i]],{i,n}] but not work. Not show three graphs, each of a file.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!